# Books for transport layer protocol implementation in Computer Networks

Tags: network-programming, linux-kernel, network-protocols

I am trying to implement a transport layer protocol for my project. I am going to use Linux as my operating system. Could you please suggest me some books or links that explain the implementation of transport layer (like TCP)? Thank you..

Thanks,
Bala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the latest (December 2008) book dedicated to this one and only topic is
[TCP/IP Architecture, Design and Implementation in Linux](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470147733).
772 pages, enough to keep anyone busy for a little while.
Note that it doesn't cover UDP, deferred to a future book.
Caveat: Even though the book was released end dec 2008, the base kernel tree it describes is a 2.4.20 one. OTOH, I don't think the TCP/IP stack has changed that much since then. The author announces in his preface that 2.6 specifics will be covered in a future edition.

Answer (score 0):

*The* book on the topic - [TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 2: The Implementation](http://www.kohala.com/start/tcpipiv2.html), by W. Richard Stevens the great.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know any book that deals with the implementation in Linux?

Comment: Here's first Google hit: http://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Network-Internals-Christian-Benvenuti/dp/0596002556 Disclamer - I haven't read it.